# Dependent javascript object properties

Tags: javascript

How can I do something like this in javascript?

```
obj = {
    prop1 = 0;
    prop2 = 0;
    prop3 = prop1 + prop2;
}
```

So when obj.prop1 is updated so will obj.prop3 automatically.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to make `prop3` getter/setter, see example

```js
var obj = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 4,
    get prop3() {
      return this.prop1 + this.prop2; 
    }
};

console.log(obj.prop3);
obj.prop1 = 6;
console.log(obj.prop3);
```